# I can't make my page scrollable with css

Tags: css, scroll, responsive

I'm unable to make my page scrollable.  The code is:

```
    body{
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#triangle-down { width: 0px; height: 0px;
border-left: 200px solid transparent;
border-right:200px solid transparent;
border-top: 230px solid white;
margin-left: 475px;
position:fixed;;
top: 65px;
z-index: -1;
  }
div.topName {
  margin-bottom:6px;
   margin-left: 615px;
   position: relative;
   z-index:1;

}

body {
background-image: url("pictures/UHT_Plovdiv.png");
background-size: cover;
width: 50%;
background-color:0099CC;
}
div.boxwhitetop {
solid white ;
background-color: white;
width: 1200px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 30px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 80px;
}
divMainbox{
border-radius: 35px;
background: white;
top: 7px;
left: -525px;
width: 1050px;
height: 1000px;
position:absolute;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-animation: fadein 4.5s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
-moz-animation: fadein 4.5s; /* Firefox < 16 */
-ms-animation: fadein 4.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-animation: fadein 4.5s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
animation: fadein 4.5s;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

My github link is https://github.com/nedzone/uht-yniversitet, please tell me where my issue is and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close your div in line number 23 in nachalna stanica.html, the page will start to scroll

```
<div id="triangle-down"></div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERRY MUCH THAT WAS THE CASE !!

Answer (score 0):

If everything is going in the divMainbox then you shouldn't have a height on it. Otherwise it won't allow that container to resize based on the size of the content inside. Otherwise if you do want a specific height on that container then you should add a `overflow-y: scroll;` to it instead of the `overflow: hidden;` that you have now. This would allow you the container to have height, but also allow the user to scroll within it. Perhaps this is the trouble your having.